# why do I keep getting child out of range error?

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am using this python script to convert xml's to csv:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text),
                     int(member[4][4].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def main():
    for directory in ['train', 'test']:
        image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'papers/{}'.format(directory))
        xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
        xml_df.to_csv('data/{}_labels.csv'.format(directory), index=None)
        print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')


main()
```

when I run it on xml's that look like this:

```
<annotation>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <filename>BROWN, M M-1.jpg</filename>
    <size>
        <width>2200</width>
        <height>3217</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>DOB</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>121</xmin>
            <ymin>296</ymin>
            <xmax>625</xmax>
            <ymax>346</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

I keep getting this

> int(member[4][0].text), IndexError: child index out of range' error

Can anyone help me figure out what's the problem? I'm not sure why the error keeps popping up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to sample XML, the *bundbox* element is located at node 5, not 4. By the way, there's no need to use `pandas` for csv migration. Consider the `csv` (built-in module as of Python 3). Also below shows you can use numbered indexing, `[##]`, or `find()` for the nodes: *xmin*, *ymin*, *xmin*, and *xmax*.

```
# ALL STANDARD LIBRARY MODULES
import os, glob, csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def xml_to_csv(path):

    with open("Output.csv", "w") as f:
        cw = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n")
        cw.writerow(['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax'])

        for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
            tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
            root = tree.getroot()

            for member in root.findall('object'):
                value = (root.find('filename').text,
                         int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                         int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                         member[0].text,
                         int(member[5][0].text),
                         int(member[5][1].text),
                         int(member[5].find('ymin').text),
                         int(member[5].find('ymax').text)
                        )
                cw.writerow(value)
```

Comment: Thanks man. The boundbox needing to be [5] worked perfectly. and thank you for your suggestion about not needing pandas.